# Run a tensorflow saved model in electron app

Tags: tensorflow, electron

We have a custom tensorflow saved model. We will build the app that uses this model with electron.

How we can use this model in an electron app?

We can't convert it to a tensorflow.js model we need a not supported feature.

One of our solution ideas is to use on macos the core-ml engine this works only on macos and we don't have a solution idea for windows.

Thanks for any idea or help

Update:

We will use the model in the inference mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would provide more details about how you would like to use Tensorflow in Electron, but in my answer I am assuming you only need to run inference.

**In that case you need to:**

1. Ensure python environment is setup (you can use virtualenv or something similar)
2. Ensure you have installed all your requirements like tensorflow - `pip -m requirements.txt`
3. Install python shell package via npm - `npm install --save python-shell`
4. Write a python script that executes your interaction with tensorflow
5. Use pyshell to execute your script. Here is an example:

```
var pyshell = require('python-shell');

pyshell.run('tensorflow.py',  function  (err, results)  {
    if  (err)  throw err;
    console.log('tensorflow.py finished.');
    console.log('results', results);
});
```

Finally: The other option is to write a [node module](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules) in c++ that interacts with the [Tensorflow C++](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/cc) API.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What do you think  about this solution, i install docker in the background and use tensorflow serving on mac and windows?